# Visual Studio Code: Update January 2024 (version 1.86) No longer shows console.log messages in terminal

Tags: javascript, react-native, debugging

I am fairly inexperienced in the dev world but I've been building an app using react native, using a course to help me learn. One of the most instrumental tools I've been using is console.log() to make sure what I'm writing is being called in the ways that it should be.

However, this latest update just happened and now none of my console logs are showing up in the terminal as they were before.

for example, my app has persistence for user login and used to display about 4-5 console messages to show that it was working correctly, but now, no matter where they are put they simply do not log anything.

example code:

```
      if (event === "SIGNED_IN") {
        console.log("We signed in");
        setUser(session.user);
        setAuth(true);
      } else if (event === "SIGNED_OUT") {
        console.log("We signed out");
        setUser(null);
        setAuth(false);
      }
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?
Or what exactly happened?

I tried looking for answers through Google, but nothing seems to relate to the issue mentioned.
I tried looking through the update notes, but I didn't see anything related to console debugging. I tried pushing to git, redownloading, and reinstalling through the yarn to see if that fixes, that however did not work.

As a side note I am running this with expo, I opened a new folder/file, tried console log, that worked.
and came back to this project, and ran expo start instead of yarn start, and suddenly its working again.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am running this with expo.

it seems like the fix is to run expo start instead of yarn start for some reason.
yarn still shows no console logs as of right now.
I would still like to know why this is the case if anybody knows